# How to reproduce Instagram Lo-Fi filter in Photoshop?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, digital, iphone

[image]

I used the Instagram Lo-Fi filter a lot and wonder how I can reproduce the effect in Photoshop...

Comment: I think this kind of effect falls under on-topic here (it's a post-processing effect, after all), and we've got plenty of "how do I do this photo effect in this program" questions already, don't we?

Comment: (As I understand the previous conversation, it's the questions like "how do I work the layers dialog" or "how do I configure keyboard shortcuts" which are off-topic, along with questions that fit better on the Graphic Design site.)

Comment: http://www.niksoftware.com/colorefexpro/usa/index.php?view=intro/filters.shtml is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find lots of Instagram filters as Photoshop Action, created by Daniel Box. They are good and really useful :)

http://dbox.tumblr.com/post/5426249009/instagram-filters-as-photoshop-actions

Answer (score 3):

This looks to me like just a contrast boost and slight desaturation. Try duplicating the background layer, setting the Layer Mode to Overlay, then using a Hue/Saturation adjustment layer, drop the saturation a little.

If this produces blown highlights, you can either lower the opacity of the Overlay layer, or instead use a Levels adjustment and bring the left-most (black) point in to the centre more.