# How to recreate Instagram Lux effect in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, fireworks, instagram

I am just wondering if anyone knows how to recreate the instagram lux effect with photoshop,

here is an example of before and after of the lux effect

**Before Lux**

[image: Before Lux]

**After Lux**

[image: After Lux]

Answer (score 3):

I borrowed your image to try it in Image View plus more 3, which I made myself so I know all the underlying algorithms.

[image: Lux recreate]

I think this is pretty close, albeit the colours may be a bit different (my weakness as I am colour deficient).

What I did was:

1. Local contrast enhancement. Adobe calls this "clarity". It is similar to the unsharp mask with a very large radius.
2. Boost saturation. My program does this in the L*a*b space. Other software may do this in other spaces (e.g. HSV) which can result in different colours. It may also be a selective saturation boost like a proprietary "vibrance".

But I would conclude it is these two operations that is incorporated into "Lux"; a local contrast enhancement, and a saturation booster of some sort.